# $\left\| A \right\| \le \varepsilon \Rightarrow \left\| {\mathop A\limits^{\_\_} } \right\| \le \varepsilon$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose

- $A \in {C^{n \times n}}$
- $\left\| A \right\| \le \varepsilon$ such that $\left\| . \right\|$ is matrix norm subordinate to the euclidean vector norm.

Is this true that $\left\| {\mathop A\limits^{\_\_} } \right\| \le \varepsilon $ and $\left\| {{A^*}} \right\| \le \varepsilon $?

Comment: $\|\overline{A}\|=\|A\|=\|A^*\|$, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$
\|A\| = \sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A^*A)} = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|
$$
In order to show that $\|A^*\| = \|A\|$, it suffices to note that $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues.

In order to show that $\|\overline A\| = \|A\|$, it suffices to note that $\|\overline A x\| = \|A \overline x\|$.